# Swipe between UISegmentedControl to view different Collection Views

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol, uipageviewcontroller

What is the best possible way to swipe left and right to toggle between two segments in a segmented view, and show different content for each segment selected. The content I want to show for each segment is a collection view of images. So segment "public" shows one collection view, and "friends" shows another.

[image]

I am not sure if I should use `UIScrollView` or use a `UIPageViewController` or if there is another option. This is close to what I want but it is in objective-c and I am looking for a much simpler solution in swift. [github example](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers)

Answer (score -1):

Use swipe gesture to got this.

And keep trak of currently showing VC. change as per you require.

[Use this link for swipe gesture.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927688/gesture-recognizer-swipe-on-uiimageview)