# How to create swipe gesture for right/left in detailed view UIimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am working on a food app in which each `tableViewCell` shows different recipes names. When a user taps on a recipe (in a cell), a detailed view will be opened.

I am now trying to implement a swipe gesture for `UIImageView` which shows different images on swipe. How do I implement that?

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeImage:)];

 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeImage:)];


 // Setting the swipe direction.
 [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
 [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
 // Adding the swipe gesture on image view

 [Allimages addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
 [Allimages addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];



- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe{

 NSInteger indexPath;

 if (indexPath==0) {

 if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {


   arrayimage=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@ "BBQ Chicken Pizza.jpg",@ "roastchickensteaks.jpg", nil];


   swipee =  (swipee > 0)?  ([arrayimage count]-1):
    swipee%[arrayimage count];


    Allimages.image=[UIImage imageNamed:  [arrayimageobjectAtIndex:indexPath]];
    }}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/apDEw.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiURG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q799.png

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
 [imageview setUserInteractionEnabled=YES];
```

create object for swipegesture recognizer class

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onSwipe)];

[leftSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
```

Add swipeGesture to imageView

```
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

-(void)onSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer)swipe{
 if(swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
  {
   NSLog(@"leftSwipe");
  }
}
```

if you want more information: just check
 [Gesture recognizer (swipe) on UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927688/gesture-recognizer-swipe-on-uiimageview)

Comment: if you found useful accept this answer..so that it will be helpful for more users

Comment: But when i implement this code every cell  category get  theses images.which is show on first.

Comment: it means each cell showing same images. your line is not clear

Comment: yes ur right . i want different cell have different images.Then 2nd cell show different images.
Look at this link

Comment: yes ur right . i want different cell have different images.Then 2nd cell show different images.
Look at this link..see in Features.

http://codecanyon.net/item/ios-recipe-app/10960556

Multiple images per recipe.

Comment: add your code.. and simulator images to the question .Then it will be easy to answer

Answer (score 0):

In your detail View Make `UserInteractionEnabledt` to YES of your imageview.

```
 [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Adding a Swipe Gesture Events

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

// Setting the swipe direction.
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

// Adding the swipe gesture on image view
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

And Handle Swipe Gesture Events using below code.

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
    }

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");   
    } 

}
```

Or else You can use Third Party Tool

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagedflowview

Comment: i want different cell have different images.Then 2nd cell show different images.
Look at this link..see in Features.

http://codecanyon.net/item/ios-recipe-app/10960556

Multiple images per recipe;