# How to change a UIView background colour upon swipe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uibackgroundcolor

how can I change the UIView background colour by a SwipeGesture?  e.g. Green for a Left Swipe and Red for a Right Swipe.  Thank you very much.

code doesn't work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:24.0/255 green:96.0/255 blue:120.0/255 alpha:0.5];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

    - (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

        if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {

            self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:138.0/255 green:24.0/255 blue:47.0/255 alpha:1.0];
            NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
        }

        if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {

            self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:24.0/255 green:96.0/255 blue:120.0/255 alpha:1.0];
            NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should show some of the code that you tried and didn't work, if you didn't try anything, I suggest to do before asking :)

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: @TallentSiu  I added a working codes for you. Please check it out below.  I appreciate upvote and/or accept answer if you found it working.  :) Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have separate swipe handler to make it work. This works great.

> Your codes in setting up your UISwipeGestureRecognizer should look
>   like this.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];

    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

> And your swipe handle  should be like this.

```
- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
    self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:24.0/255 green:96.0/255 blue:120.0/255 alpha:1.0];
}

- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
    self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:138.0/255 green:24.0/255 blue:47.0/255 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an imageView property in the `interface` of the ViewController file.
    @property (weak, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    }
```

Handling Swipe Gesture Events
//newImage and newImage1 are the images files name in your `project` or `ImageAssets` 
    - (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

```
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myNewImage.png"];
    }

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");   
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myNewImage1.png"];
    } 

}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding. [refer to this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17927906/5807290)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your code doesn't work on my case as it will first change the imageView and then change the background colour for a second swipe only.  Can I change both the imageView and the background colour by a same swipe?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes when do you want to change the imageView

Comment: You need to declare the imageView as a property and change the image. Please check my updated answer.